# Collision free unique id generation for an event driven application

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

I am looking for a way to generate a collision free random id which will serve as a unique identifier for an event driven architecture.

I want to assign a unique id to every event that is received by my receiver application.

For starters, i began with exploring java's UUID and also Message digest algorithms but they seem to be collision prone.

The reason for such requirement is my events will be updated over a period of time with new info and i dont want data corruption due to duplicate Ids..

Comment: UUID is fine. Why do you think it is "collision prone"?

Comment: Do the unique IDs you want to generate have to be hard to guess?  Can you use sequential IDs instead?  You should edit your question to answer the six questions I give in "[Unique Random Identifiers](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Unique_Random_Identifiers)", as they will help you decide how best to generate unique identifiers.

Comment: From the Wikipedia page [Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier): _While the probability that a UUID will be duplicated is not zero, it is close enough to zero to be negligible._